# Return Each Vowels

Tags: java

```
public class one
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {       
    }

    public static int vowels( String s )
    {
        int countA = 0; int countE = 0; int countI = 0; 
        int countO = 0; int countU = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'a')
            {
                countA++;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i) == 'e')
            {
                countE++;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i) == 'i')
            {
                countI++;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i) == 'o')
            {
                countO++;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i) == 'u')
            {
                countU++;
            }
        }
        return countA; return countE; return countI;
        return countO; return countU;
    }
}
```

The program I'am making will count the number of vowels in a string. I'am trying to get a way to apply it to main and output the result. I tried doing different returns like below but its not working..

Comment: A method can only return one value - but that value can be a collection or an array. How did you expect to *use* the results of this?

Comment: I planned to use a scanner for user input and then output: The vowel a appears 0 time(s).....
The vowel e appears 2 time(s)....etc

Comment: But how were you expecting to be able to get the results back from the method? Were you expecting to call it multiple times? Consider returning an array of 5 elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only return a single value from a method call. However, that value can be an array or a collection.

Two options to consider:

- Change your method to accept a second parameter of "the character to count" occurrences of, and call it 5 times.
- Change your method to return an array, where element 0 is the count of As, element 1 is the count of Es etc

The first approach is cleaner and more reusable (IMO) but less efficient. You'd have something like:

```
String text = ...;
System.out.println("The vowel a appears " + count(text, 'a') + " times.");
System.out.println("The vowel e appears " + count(text, 'e') + " times.");
System.out.println("The vowel i appears " + count(text, 'i') + " times.");
System.out.println("The vowel o appears " + count(text, 'o') + " times.");
System.out.println("The vowel u appears " + count(text, 'u') + " times.");

...

private static int count(String text, char charToCount) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == charToCount) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement exits your method an returns *one* value that you have specified. All the rest `return`s are simply not reachable, the method had already been left by the time you'd get to them.

Any method has only one return type (read the signature of the method you have written yourself) and returns a single value that can only be assigned to a single variable. But since you didn't write anything like `return coutA, countE, ...;`, I suppose you didn't want to assign the result to multiple variables simultaneously, but instead was expecting some generator-like behavior like the `yield` statement in Python and C# provides. Java doesn't have generators built into the language and you have to create an anonymous class that implements `java.lang.Iterable`.

But **in your case there's no need to do it**. What you really need is either:

- call this method for each vowel separately, or
- use some container that will hold all of your results.

For the first option you will have something like:

```
public static int countVowel(String str, char vowel) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == vowel) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you want to count all of your vowels using one loop, you can use an array, a Map, or your own object with corresponding fields to store the result and pass it back to the caller.